# JmsListener - Receive message from topic

Tags: jms, spring-jms

Is there any way to receive message from service bus topic without using the `@JmsListener` annotation? The issue with using the `@JmsListener` and `@EnableJms` annotations is that as soon as I start the application it will receive the message. Instead I need to create an API and on hitting that only I need to get the message from topic.

Below is a sample implementation using `@JmsListener`:

```java
@JmsListener(destination="topic",
             containerFactory="jmscontainerFactory",
             subscription="subscriptionName")
public void getMessage(Object obj) {
    Log.info(obj);
}
```

I tried going through some documentations and all, but I didn't get an exact solution.

Comment: Use Spring's [`JmsTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html). One of the "receive" methods will allow you to receive messages synchronously rather than asynchronously like with `@JmsListener`.